# How to erase duplicates of Child array in Parent array without hardcoring index

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have two arrays as fallows,

```
NSArray *First=@[@"a", @"b", @"c",@"d", @"e", @"f",@"g", @"h", @"i", @"j", @"k"];
NSArray *Second=@[@"a",@"d", @"e",@"g",@"i"];
```

Now In a

```
 NSMutableArray *Result=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

When i NSLog result array i wnated the output as

[
b
c
f
h
j
k
]

Means the result array should delete the elements in second array from first array,And the condition is Witout usuing`removeObjectAtIndex` Method

Thanks in-advance.

Comment: Jakub answer is correct and give first. so i suggest you to accept his answer.

Comment: i have already upvoted.

Comment: Ofcourse i am,Got the exact solution for my problem right?

Cheerup Bro!i WAS just kidding! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (id object in First)
    if (![Second containsObject:object]) [Result addObject:object];
```

Answer (score 2):

Following is the code to get output as you want Without using removeObjectAtIndex Method.Try this :

```
NSArray *First=@[@"a", @"b", @"c",@"d", @"e", @"f",@"g", @"h", @"i", @"j", @"k"];
    NSArray *Second=@[@"a",@"d", @"e",@"g",@"i"];

    NSMutableArray *result=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    for (NSString *tempChar in First) {
        if (![Second containsObject:tempChar]) {

            [result addObject:tempChar];
            NSLog(@"result arr :%@",result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// *** Most Efficient way to achieve with just 3 Lines of code ***
// *** `NSMutableSet` will do the job for you. ***
// *** method `minusSet` performs subtraction operation between two given sets. ***
NSMutableSet *first = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithArray:@[@"a", @"b", @"c",@"d", @"e", @"f",@"g", @"h", @"i", @"j", @"k"]];
NSMutableSet *second = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithArray:@[@"a",@"d", @"e",@"g",@"i"]];
[first minusSet:second];
NSLog(@"%@",first);
```

Comment: Just a note: this may not work as expected if the 1st set has duplicates (as converting it to a set will remove them).

Answer (score 1):

Without loop you can archive it with `NSSet`

```
NSMutableSet *firstSet1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray: First];
NSSet *secondSet2 = [NSSet setWithArray: Second];
[firstSet1 minusSet: secondSet2];
NSArray * Result = [firstSet1 allObjects];
```

Comment: @AshokLondhe I have tested this code and its working bro, May be there is problem in your code.

Comment: Can you tell me whats wrong, So I can improve myself??

Comment: @VirajSavaj it gives output:   g,
    d,
    i,
    e,
    a

Comment: @AshokLondhe, thanks dude, I got problem. Thank you so much, it was silly mistake,.

Comment: @VirajSavaj its fine.